# Replace string with another in DataColumn of DataTable

Tags: c#

I have `DataTable` which retrieves multiple columns and rows. One of its column ("Comments") Contains data `*`. I want replace that character with `\n`.

```
dtOutput = Generix.getTickets(DateTime.Parse("1-1-1900"), DateTime.Now,"",iTicket, "", "", "", "","",iDispatched,uCode);
string sOutput = "";
foreach (DataRow drOutput in dtOutput.Rows)
{
   sOutput += ((sOutput == "") ? "" : "~");
   foreach (DataColumn dcOutput in dtOutput.Columns)
   {                                    
      sOutput += ((sOutput == "") ? "" : "|") + Convert.ToString(drOutput[dcOutput]);
   }
}
```

I am able to merge all columns in one String.
But how to replace character with another in store it in Same string as of `"sOutput"`.

Comment: It seems here you are trying to concatenate all the values present in a row and showing the result value in the `Comments` column of the respective row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In foreach loop you can modify the row by accessing against the column index ("Comments") and use string.Replace to replace `"*"` with `"\n"`

```
foreach (DataRow drOutput in dtOutput.Rows)
{
     drOutput["Comments"] = drOutPut["Comments"].ToString().Replace('*','\n');
     //your remaining code
}
```

Comment: I think you need to Escape `"\\n"` ! !

Comment: @V4Vendetta, thanks for pointing that out, I am not sure about it, so I replaced it with `string.Replace(char, char)`

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    row.SetField<string>("Comment", 
       row.Field<string>("Comment").Replace("*", @"\n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (DataColumn dcOutput in dtOutput.Columns)
{                    
    sOutput += ((sOutput == "") ? "" : "|") + Convert.ToString((dcOutput.ColumnName=="Comments") ? drOutput[dcOutput].ToString().Replace("*","\n") : drOutput[dcOutput]);
}
```